# Write a program that prompts the user to enter a telephone number expressed in letters and outputs the corresponding telephone number in digits. I

Tags: java

I have the following task:

> Write a program that prompts the user to enter a telephone number expressed in letters and outputs the corresponding telephone number in digits. If the user enters more than seven letters, then process only the first seven letters. Also output the – (hyphen) after the third digit. Allow the user to use both uppercase and lowercase letters as well as spaces between words.

Below is what I have tried, but can't get it to work. Please advise.

```
package assignment;

import java.util.*;
public class Question3 {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String telephone_letter;
    int index;



    System.out.println("Enter phone number :");
    telephone_letter = keyboard.nextLine();
    char aChar[] = telephone_letter.toCharArray();
    for(index=0;index<telephone_letter.length();index++){
    int[] number;
        number = new int[index];

        switch (aChar[index]) 
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                number[index] = 2;
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'd':
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                number[index] = 3;
                break;
            case 'G':
            case 'g':
            case 'H':
            case 'h':
            case 'I':
            case 'i':
                number[index] = 4;
                break;
            case 'J':
            case 'j':
            case 'K':
            case 'k':
            case 'L':
            case 'l':
                number[index] = 5;
                break;
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
            case 'N':
            case 'n':
            case 'O':
            case 'o':
                number[index] = 6;
                break;
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
            case 'Q':
            case 'q':
            case 'R':
            case 'r':
            case 'S':
            case 's':
                number[index] = 7;
                break;
            case 'T':
            case 't':
            case 'U':
            case 'u':
            case 'V':
            case 'v':
                number[index] = 8;
                break;
            case 'W':
            case 'w':
            case 'X':
            case 'x':
            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
            case 'Z':
            case 'z':
                number[index] = 9;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Digit");
                break;


        }

    }

        System.out.println("achar" + number[0]+number[1]+number[2]+"-"+number[4]+number[5]+number[6]+number[7]);


    }
}
```

I am having problem to match 
aChar[index] 
to
number[index] .

I need to get input from a String then get the char from it then change it to numbers. I am not sure where i gone wrong, i am still newbie to java.

Comment: What about this program is not working?

Comment: "but [I] cant get it to work" -- How does your program not work?  Do you get errors?  What input do you give it?  What is the expected vs actual output?

Comment: What part of the code is giving you issues? We won't read a wall of code for trying to get in your head.

Comment: You should mention a specific problem

Comment: P.S.  Don't try to flesh out your question by posting multiple comments with more information.  Edit your question to add additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
for(index=0;index<telephone_letter.length();index++){
    int[] number;
```

Create your number array outside of the for loop.  Right now, you're creating a new array every time you increment.

Comment: thanks dude, you helped me alot.

Comment: An up vote and an accepted answer are the right kind of thank you ;)

Comment: i accepted the answer , but cant do up vote till i got 15 rep, just got to find out about this website.